# xslt xml to html : how to match an element that its name starts with xxx?

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xpath

This is a problem I came across. To prevent h1 to be duplicated, in xml every h1 tag will have a radom number after h1. And the source xml and the wanted html are shown below:

source xml:

```
<h1_JW1XRT>Hello1</h1_JW1XRT>
<h1_JXZRIE>Hello2</h1_JXZRIE>
```

convert into html

```
<h1 id="h1_JW1XRT">Hello1</h1>
<h1 id="h1_JXZRIE">Hello2</h1>
```

how can i write this template?

Comment: what code-base will you be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(), 'h1')]">
  <h1 id="{name()}"><xsl:apply-templates/></h1>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the following XML document** (the provided XML fragment, wrapped in a single top element -- to become a well-formed XML document):

```
<t>
    <h1_JW1XRT>Hello1</h1_JW1XRT>
    <h1_JXZRIE>Hello2</h1_JXZRIE>
</t>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<h1 id="h1_JW1XRT">Hello1</h1>
<h1 id="h1_JXZRIE">Hello2</h1>
```

**Explanation**: Proper use of the standard XPath function **[`starts-with()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-starts-with)**

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin, Thanks for this observation. Fixed.

Comment: thanks, it works. but how to match something starts with h1 but not h1home? <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(), 'h1')]" And not('h1home')>?

Comment: @user1661755 Start a new question. Also, XML in the comment feed is very hard to read.

Comment: @user1661755, I understand that you may have many questions -- please ask them *separately* as new SO questions -- the comments format is not good for expressing code or structured data. Also, you would get better understanding faster if you read a good book on XSLT and XPath. I have provided a list of good resources here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339930/any-good-xslt-tutorial-book-blog-site-online/341589#341589